# java spring security config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a code below which is an appoinment Hospital System for users.
But securityConfig part didn't work. I get the error:

The bean 'delegatingApplicationListener', defined in class path resource [userManagementSystemHospital/hospitalSystem/config/SecurityConfig.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Here the code;

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
</dependency

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```